# Are there any jsf component to mask passwords?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, passwords

I used h: inputSecret into the database of passwords but the search screen use h: outputText and passwords appear there is some component ready for this need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will suit your needs:

```
<h:inputSecret value="#{testBean.password}" 
               disabled="true" 
               readonly="true" 
               redisplay="true"/>
```

Example:

[image: Example]